# MathJax with WebPack ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, mathjax

I would like to put formulas in my webpage, which uses (dotnet Kestrel). I do not want to load javascript libraries from the net, so I am using webpack and npm for my packages. 
My problem is, that I find it impossible to load MathJax. I have tried the following:

```
import 'mathjax-full';
require('mathjax-full'); // << not the error itself
import MathJax from 'mathjax-full';
```

The most annoying error that I get is this:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I must do something obviously wrong. The error message comes from the MathJax internals. I have also tried to import `requirejs`, as some forums mentioned that as some kind of "workaround". The error I get with it is when I run WebPack:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
```

Has anybody succeeded with MathJax on WebPack?

Comment: Have you try to use the cdn ? As I know mathjax do not need to include with webpack

Comment: I do not want to load javascript libraries from the net

Comment: If you include everything you want in webpack it will include the bundle size

Comment: I do not see how could it be any smaller by including packages from 3rdparty websites

Comment: Please read about how cdn work

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problems as you plus a million more. MathJax is really not WebPack-friendly.

My solution for Angular:

```
npm install --save mathjax
```

Extend the `"scripts"` array of `angular.json` with:

```
"node_modules/mathjax/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"
```

And now to call MathJax APIs, DO NOT use `import` of any kind. The `mathjax` module sets its `main` to `es5/node-main.js`, which uses an ugly hack to call `require()` at runtime, which is the ultimate source of trouble you saw.

Instead, do this:

```
declare var MathJax;
```

Now you may complain that this way you have no type information. Well, the fact is that not even `mathjax-full` has good type information for methods inside this global object: they inject the methods (such as `MathJax.typeset()`) at runtime and their types are declared using `[name: string]: any;`.

If your really want type information, you're probably better off declaring it yourself, e.g.:

```
declare interface MathJaxGlobal {
  typeset(elems: HTMLElement[]);
}
declare var MathJax: MathJaxGlobal;
```